# How to pass array of parameter types to Type[]?

Tags: c#, reflection

***Scenario:*** I have App.Config file in which there are certain methods and I want to call them through Reflection. While doing this I also need to tell the *Type* of parameters being passed to that method. I'm retrieving the list of parameter types of that method at runtime like this:

```
ParameterInfo[] parameters = magicType.GetMethod("ItsMagic").GetParameters();
```

But I don't know how to put this array in following function:

```
magicType.GetMethod("ItsMagic", new Type[] {parameters.Cast<Type>()});
```

It results in following error:

Error:  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Type'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Any suggestions how to achieve that?

Comment: I don't know, but you seem to do unnecessary work... `magicType.GetMethod("ItsMagic")` already gets you the *MethodInfo* object. Querying the type object again for the same method with the parameters obtained from the *MethodInfo* object returns just the same *MethodInfo* object again. Also you cannot cast the *ParameterInfo* type to the *System.Type* type, obviously. Look at L.B.'s answer of how to obtain the parameter type from the *ParameterInfo* objects in the array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
parameters.Select(p=>p.ParameterType).ToArray()
```

---

```
magicType.GetMethod("ItsMagic", parameters.Select(p=>p.ParameterType).ToArray() );
```

Comment: I have made some changes in  the code above. Please go through it again

Comment: @Sadiq, you cannot cast a *ParameterInfo* object to *System.Type*, because *ParameterInfo* does not inherit from *System.Type*. What is the problem with L.B.'s answer?